# Does a verb need to be preceded by "to"?

Tags: verbs, prepositions

A (very) common verb is "to be", another is "to have". But you can also say that "have" is a common verb.

The question is, when does a verb (on its own) have to be preceded by the preposition "to"? Is it stylistic? Is there a rule?

Comment: Are you referring to **mentions** of verbs not to **uses** of verbs?  For example, saying "*Come* and *go* are verbs of motion" instead of saying "*To come* and *to go* are verbs of motion."

Comment: @tchrist Yes. So theoretically, verbs in inverted commas.

Comment: *To* has grammaticalized into an infinitive marker in *to be* and is no longer a preposition.  Since the two are separate words and *to* isn't part of the verb, it seems rather confused to refer to the verb as *to be*.  Still, most people will understand what you mean because it's such a common practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it doesn't. Many of the prototypical uses for the infintive (*be* or *have* or *walk*) are preceded by *to*; and, perhaps more to the point, there is so little verbal morphology left in English that if you cite *have* it may be unclear whether you are referring to the infinitive (as in *I can have* or *in order to have*) or to a finite verb form (such as *I have* or *they have*). So it is customary to cite the infinitive with *to*.

Whether an infinitive requires *to* before it in use depends on the syntactic context:

- If you're treating it as a noun (as in *To err is human*) it always requires *to*.
- After auxiliary verbs such as *want*, *ought*, and *intend*, after adjectives such as *required*, *meant*, *compelled*, after phrases
  like *in order*, it takes *to*.
- After modal auxiliaries such as *can*, *should*, *may*, *must*, *will*, it does not take *to*.
- And the words *need* and *dare* (sometimes called 'semi-modals') can take either, at least in some constructions: *I need to go*, *Do you need to go?* but (at least for some speakers) alternatively, *Need you go?*

Apart from this last case, it is not optional: some constructions require *to*, and others forbid it.

Comment: Your _need_ construction: isn't that just treating the infinitive like a noun, the object of _need_? I need water. I need cheese. I need to go.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇: you could analyse it that way if you want; but that loses the parallel with _want_, _ought_ etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few optional examples:

I helped John (to) decide where to have a holiday.

I assisted my mother (to) find a good restaurant.

John demanded Peter (to) pay back the money.

Alice requested John (to) make a cake.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I meant when the verb is used on its own, e.g. the verb *have* vs. the verb *to have*.